# Angular http request returning an array of Observables correctly in Chrome but as empty array in Internet Explorer

Tags: angular, google-chrome, http, internet-explorer-11

This is the service call that is not working in IE11 but is in Chrome. In IE11, it is just returning an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

[image: service call that is not working in IE111]

UPDATE:
I have narrowed down the issue to the fact that withCredentials is not working. Does anybody know why withCredentials will work with the previous function this is attached to but not this one?

Comment: Where do you invoke the getCart?

Comment: @huanfeng in a subscription of another service. It is a chain of services. the previous one is similar to this one

Comment: @huanfeng I should clarify. It is returning something, but only part of the response.return_cart_info

Comment: Hello @KevinWilde I think arrow function will not work in IE 11 you should have to use function instead of arrow function. and also please do check your console in IE browser..

Comment: @kushalshah Please look at the update.

Comment: I want to confirm with you whether there is any error or warning in the console of the IE browser? Is there any simple way to reproduce the issue? If yes, please provide the detailed steps for producing the issue. We can try to refer to your steps and try to check for the issue.